# Web hosting announced downtime and how it affects FORWARD domain names?

Tags: web-hosting, domains, domain-forwarding

Our web hosting provider that holds our FORWARD domain names announced that at some point in the next couple weeks they will be migrating servers and that this will cause a 5-10 minute downtime at some point in that week during what happens to be our core business hours.  They cite for technical reasons it is impossible to give an exact date or time when this downtime will occur.

My questions are:

1. If my domains are set to FORWARD to a static IP on servers not hosted by the web hosting provider in question then will this affect the DNS servers correctly routing to my website?
2. Are their legitimate technical reasons for such a wide window of time, or could this just be a blanket statement to cover laziness in not being more organized with their server migrations?
3. Are such downtimes normal for web hosting providers, or should I start to consider other providers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downtime's are normal for major web hosts. It may be a scheduled maintenance on the server.
But they can provide a rough time period.

Any ways I suggest you to use a 3rd Party DNS server to bypass such issues,
I personally use Cloudflare. And It's free too.

When ever you met a situation like this, change the A Record off your root domain to new server, The propagation takes below 5 Mts. You won't even miss a single email by such issues.

If you are experiencing downtime more than 5%. Then it might be the time to look up new host.